# Is it possible to pass multiple parameter to controller before click submit button for validation purpose in mvc?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, validation

Is it possible to pass multiple parameters to a controller before clicking  the submit button for validation purposes?

I am currently using **Username already exists** validation. In that I passed the username to the controller for validation purpose.
Now I have three fields OrganizationName, OrganizationID, UserName. Now I want to pass this OrganizationName and 
OrganizationID with username to that CheckForDuplication json validation for another purpose.

**My Model (UserRegistration)**

```
   public class UserRegistration
   {
     public int LoginID { get; set; }
     [Required]       
     [Remote("CheckForDuplication", "Useregistration", ErrorMessage = "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.")]
     public string UserName { get; set; }
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
     public string Password { get; set; }
     public string OrganizationName{ get; set; }
     public int OrganizationID{get;set;}
    }
```

**My Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UserRegistration()        
     {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult CheckForDuplication(string UserName int OrganizationID)
    {          
        var data = db.Logins.Where(p => p.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
        int loginid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["uid"]);
        var equal = db.Logins.Where(p => p.UserName == UserName && p.LoginID == loginid).FirstOrDefault();

        if(data != null && equal == null)
        {
            return Json("Sorry, this name already exists", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else if(equal != null )
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else          
       {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }

    }
```

**My View**

```
       @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.OrganizationID)
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.OrganizationID)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.OrganizationID)

       @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.OrganizationName)
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.OrganizationName)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.OrganizationName)

       @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.UserName)
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.UserName)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.UserName)

       @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Password)
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Password)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Password)
```

Now I want to pass this OrganizationName, OrganizationID, and UserName to that CheckForDuplication function in the controller and also I want to pass these 3 fields' values after entering the username not before entering the username. I do not know if it is possible or not. Can anyone help me? I tried my very best to explain this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property available in [`RemoteAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) class named [`AdditionalFields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute.additionalfields%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which you need to use for this scenario, you would apply it on all the three Properties that you want to :

```
[Remote("CheckForDuplication", 
        "Useregistration", 
        ErrorMessage = "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name."),
        AdditionalFields = "OrganizationID,OrganizationName"]
public string UserName { get; set; }
        ......
        ......
[Remote("CheckForDuplication", 
        "Useregistration", 
        ErrorMessage = "Your message."),
        AdditionalFields = "UserName,OrganizationID"]
public string OrganizationName{ get; set; }
[Remote("CheckForDuplication", 
        "Useregistration", 
        ErrorMessage = "Your message."),
        AdditionalFields = "UserName,OrganizationName"]
public int OrganizationID{get;set;}
```

Comment: Why you suddenly changed your answer. ok again i have a check and let you know

Comment: @snehasusan you will also need to update your controller to accept the `OrganizationName` string.  Currently in your code, it is only accepting `UserName` and `OrganizationID` and it is also missing a comma between those two inputs.  Update it to be `public JsonResult CheckForDuplication(string UserName, int OrganizationID, string OrganizationName)`

Comment: OK I have a check and let you know

Comment: The syntax is not correct and he gave you incorrect values in the `action` and `controller` sections.  What is the name of your controller?

Comment: I have added as per u said but again it showing error near to =of  Additionalfields.  I added fields in controller to and the error is Invalid token =in class, struct,or interface member declaration

Comment: @akousmata the name my controller is useregistration

Comment: @akousmata the controller and action name is correct only I think

Comment: @snehasusan ok I was just checking on the controller.  The error near additional fields is caused by the parentheses being in the wrong place.  Change this `ErrorMessage = "Your message.",)
        AdditionalFields = "UserName,OrganizationID"]` to this `ErrorMessage = "Your message.",
        AdditionalFields = "UserName,OrganizationID")]` on all 3 of your properties and it should compile.  Then if it still isn't working consult this tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx

Comment: OK I have a check and let you know

Comment: Now error removed but I mentioned one point I think u forgot that. That is after entering username only It have to pass this 3fields value to controller .but after entering organizationid it pass the value to controller  may I know it is possible

Comment: Yes I itself found the solution to pass the three fields at a time that is your first answer in single remote validation  have to add the other fields using additional fields

Comment: I gave you the clue how to pass additional properties,  the remaining is trivial and you should be able to write the needed

Comment: I have one doubt in this Suppose if i didnt select the  organizationID  means that value will be null. At that time it wont pass the value to controller for checking validation. But i want to pass the value to controller if it is null. It is possible

Comment: If user didn't selected any value then ofcourse it would be null